# Compiling a .c file with old gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I am currently trying to compile a file in linux, call it `file.c`. I am directed to use the compiler `gcc` with the options `-ansi` and  `-pedantic` but am unsure of the exact syntax involved in actually compiling the `file.c`. Note I believe, the `gcc` compiler is supposed to from like the '98 or '99 version. I can't remember which version. Would anyone be able to help me out with this?

Let me know if more clarification is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you run `gcc -ansi -pedantic file.c`?

Comment: Did you try to simply do `gcc -ansi -pedantic file.c`?

Comment: That works! Thank you! Sorry for the not great question! I think I was messing it up inside a makefile.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling it like this:

```sh
gcc -ansi -pedantic file.c
```

Then run it with:

```
./a.out
```

[The GCC reference.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)